# How do I install valgrind on mobaxterm?

Tags: installation, valgrind, xterm

I am using windows 8 and when I try to ./configure on mobaxterm, it shows bunch of installation status check and at the end it says:

checking for a supported OS... no (cygwin)
configure: error: Valgrind is operating system specific. Sorry.

Does that mean it does not work only on my computer? or does it just not work with mobaxterm?

Answer (score 0):

Valgrind is OS specific. which means it won't compile on an unsupported plateforme, in this case cygwin.

I'm unsure why it is so, but I'm trying to find out.

Apparently mobaxterm try to compile valgrind or at least use valgrind configure file, for some reasons. I don't know what it does, but it seems you won't be able to make it work on cygwin. (But since it's been month since you asked the question, I suppose you already know that and/or you have found a workaround. )